# PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll?

Tags: pyinstaller

How to fix the below specified issue. I really don't know why is error getting.

```
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 151, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll '/tmp/_MEIk3Dbk4/cefpython3/libcef.so'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

Comment: Is it possible to import dynlib to ubuntu server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your lib 32bit <=> 64bit